# How to set trap flag without using pop instruction

Tags: x86-16

I want to set trap flag = 1, but without using pop algorithm. I know that it's possible, but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `POPF`?  Is this just a puzzle or do you have some specific constraint? I mean, you can also load the flags from the stack by abusing `IRET` but that seems like cheating.

Comment: It's a puzzle, and I got the answer, It's by using LAHF and SAHF instructions.

Comment: I thought about `SAHF` but it doesn't work.  It loads AH into the low byte of FLAGS, i.e. bits 0-7.  The trap flag is bit 8 and won't be touched by `SAHF`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, the university page said so.

Comment: Perhaps this question would have been better directed to [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

`FLAGS` is pushed onto the stack when an interrupt is generated, and popped from the stack by `IRET`.  So if you are still allowed `PUSHF`, you could do something like

```
    pushf
    pop ax
    or ax, 100h
    push ax
    call far do_iret
    ...

do_iret:
    iret
```

If `PUSHF` is not allowed, you could install an interrupt handler:

```
handler:
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    or word ptr [bp+6], 100h
    pop bp
    iret
set_trap_flag:
    push 0
    pop es
    mov [es:42h*4], offset handler
    mov [es:42h*4+2], segment handler
    int 42h
```

where `42h` is some interrupt vector that's not otherwise being used.

(Note: code not tested and could have syntax errors or bugs.)

Comment: Your answer has multiple issues! __(1)__ You're using wrong masks to set TF. __(2)__ In the IVT the offset comes before the segment.

Comment: @Fifoernik: Thanks, fixed.  I really meant the answer more as pseudocode than anything, but thanks anyway.